# set security token for SecurityNamespace.SetPermissions Method TFS

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-sdk

I want to set `Edit Build Definition` permission programmatically for a TFS Group with GUID xxx in a Team Project with GUID yyy, using `SecurityNamespace.SetPermissions` method.

Seeing the method signature, I see the security token parameter and I don't know the value that I must pass to the method.

Here, there is my method call:

```
sn.SetPermissions(securityToken, groupIdentityDescriptor, action.Bit, 0, true);
```

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

The signature for [SetPermissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/ff738548(v=vs.120)) method is:

```
public abstract AccessControlEntry SetPermissions(
    string token,
    IdentityDescriptor descriptor,
    int allow,
    int deny,
    bool merge
)
```

Take the following snippet as example:

```
securityNamespace.SetPermissions("/", identity.Descriptor ,RegistryServicePermissions.AllPermissions, 0, true);
```

- token paremeter we will pass / which means we will be granting access
  to the entire registry. If you want to grant just access to a part of
  the tree, this is the place to do it
- identityDescriptor we will pass the account/group for which we will
  be granting the parameter (more on this later)
- allow parameter we pass the value the value
  RegistryServicePermissions.AllPermissions since we want to grant
  read/write access
- deny parameter we will pass 0 since we don’t wan to deny anything
- merge we will pass true, since we want this permissions to be merged
  with existing ones (just in case)

For more information, you could check the blog below:

https://pascoal.net/2011/11/13/using-team-foundation-server-registrypart-ii-the-api/

Also, here is a useful case for your reference: [TFS API - How to get a Team's Adminstrator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22019462/tfs-api-how-to-get-a-teams-adminstrator).